# c++ folders, subfolders and files copying

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10

I would like to create a c++ program that would backup any files from an USB disk to my PC. I've already written a simple USB removable drive detection, but I didn't find any "simple" way to copy all the folders with their subfolders and files. I really don't want to use `system("copy/xcopy")`. Is there any other simple way that I could use? Also I don't really care about other OSs.

Example:
We have some folders and subfolders in 1 main folder
I want to copy everything from that main folder as if I would just drag and drop it into another folder

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: [std::filesystem::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) ? (possibly with [std::filesystem::directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator))

Comment: Explore `std::filesystem` if on C++17 capable compiler or utilize the OS-specific API calls.

Comment: Why c++? It looks like a job for some batch script.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks I'll look into it. I want to learn c++ and I'm making some random stuff that come onto my mind so I can practice and discover new things (I already have this "backup thingie" in AHK and also in batch)